# Custom Progressbar with user levels

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I want to create custom progressbar with different levels like below image;

[image]

xml code;

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"  />
```

progrss.xml;

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="360" >

<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="10"
    android:useLevel="false" >

    <size
        android:height="76dip"
        android:width="76dip" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#99cc33"
        android:startColor="#F15d36"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />

</shape>

</rotate>
```

Comment: you can use custom view and draw circle in onDraw method

Comment: Can you give me small example like how to fill color in circle parts?

Comment: what is red and green arc represent

Comment: red is representing for starting phase and green used for finishing phase

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom progress bar for your requirement

CircularProgressView

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6152

Comment: Can you tell me that how to split progressbar's circle into 5 pieces?

Comment: you can pie chart if you want to split in 5 pieces  I have used following library for implementing pie chart 

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: Can you give example ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom layout as -

```
class CircleLayout extends FrameLayout{
...
  void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
  .... 
  }
}
```

Now in onDraw() method draw a circle as having radius equals to half of min(height,width)-
height and width are height and width of Framelayout respectively 
say `int min= min(height,widht)`

```
radius = min/2
```

x and y are center point

```
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
```

Now with same radius draw two arcs say greenArc and redArc
to draw arc see this link - http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2012/04/draw-arc-on-canvas-canvasdrawarc.html